# multivariate calculus -chain rule in partial differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Solving PDE equations I realized that I am a bit confused with it the chain rule and that I have go back to basics. Maybe it is just a notation thing.

For example 
1) for one variable
$$y=f(x), \  \  x=g(t)  \implies  f=( \ ( g(t) \ ) $$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}  \quad \quad \quad (1)$$

2) for two variables
$$z=f(x,y), \ x=g(t), \ y=h(t)  \implies  z=f(g(t),h(t))$$

$$\mathbf{\frac{dz}{dt}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \mathbf{\frac{d x}{d t}} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \mathbf{\frac{d y}{d t}}  \quad \quad \quad (2)$$
$$$$

$$\mathbf{\frac{dz}{dt}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}  \quad \quad \quad (3)$$
$$$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}  \quad \quad \quad (4)$$
$$$$

Maybe it just a thing of notation convention when in case of one variable $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\frac{dx}{dt}$ (is it correct?)

Can anybody clarify the differences between 2, 3 and 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct:

- If $v$ is a function of one variable (call it $t$) you should use $dv/dt$ or $v'(t)$.
- If $v$ is a function of more than one variable (one of them being $t$) you should use $\partial v/\partial t$, or $v_t$ (or one of the other notations for a partial dervivative).

Equation (2) uses correct notation. It might help to instead write $$z(t)=f((g(t),h(t))$$

Then the derivative of $z$ is (suppressing the argument of the partial derivatives $f_1$ and $f_2$):

$$z'(t)=f_1g'(t)+f_2h'(t)$$

or using Leibniz notation:

$$\frac{dz(t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dg(t)}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dh(t)}{dt}$$

Alternatively you can write $dx/dt$ instead of $dg/dt$ and $dy/dt$ instead of $dh/dt$:

$$\frac{dz(t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

which is your equation (2).

Your equation (3) uses $\partial x/\partial t$, which is wrong because $x$ is only a function of one variable ($t$). Similarly, equation (4) uses $\partial z/\partial t$, which is the wrong notation because $z$ is a function of only one variable ($t$) (so long as you are thinking of $z$ as the composition of the function $f$ with the function $(g,h)$ rather than the function $f$ of two variables).

Comment: in terms of notation, if we deal with a function of one variable $x(t)$ wouldn't be the following $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\frac{dx}{dt}$ true?

Comment: We wouldn't write $\partial x/\partial t$ if $x$ is a function of one variable. The $\partial$ is used for partial differentiation, the $d$ is used for differentiation of functions of one variable. The standard notation is $dx(t)/dt$ or $x'(t)$. If we have $f(s,t)$ and then fix $s$ and let $x(t)=f(s,t)$, then we have $dx/dt=\partial f/\partial t$.

Comment: how does it relate to the situation in PDE's where we have a function $u(x,t)$ and we introduce new coordinates for example $\xi=x+ct, \ \nu = x - ct$ and calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial t}$ ?

Comment: You have $x(\xi,\nu)=\frac{\xi+\nu}{2}$ and $t(\xi,\nu)=\frac{\xi-\nu}{2c}$. Thus you get the function $w(\xi,\nu)=u(x(\xi,\nu),t(\xi,\nu))$. Now we have $w(\xi,\nu)$, $\xi(x,t)$ and $\nu(x,t)$ and we want to partially differentiate the composition $z(x,t)=w(\xi(x,t),\nu(x,t))$ with respect to $t$. Doing so gives $z_t(x,t)=w_\xi\xi_t(x,t)+w_\nu\nu_t(x,t)$, which is basically what you got (but defining the functions carefully here is a bit tedious and not really necessary).